# How do the push notification providers can push to user with optin?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

For example, urbanairship [1] , they claims

```
Reach each all users, not just opt-ins.
Since Rich Push messages are stored in an app’s Message Center, 
they can be delivered to all app users, not just those who have 
opted-in for push messaging.
```

Can anyone provide more hints on this? What are the drawbacks? If this method work then why still need Apple or Goolge Push API?

[1] http://urbanairship.com/products/push-messaging

Answer (score 1):

As for my understanding, "Rich push" is not really a push. It's basically a pull operation. When ever a "Rich push" is created, they are stored in their message center with a "Unique Identifier" for each "Rich Push".

This identifier can be passed along with usual Push Notification, and when user selects the app, the app has internal capability to call back to message center and retrieve the data. Even if the user didn't opt for push messages, every time user logs in the API checks for any new event since the last check. If there is any new event, message center would send the data to the user.

Since there is no limit for data, "Rich Push" can be modified to meet any requirement. For Analytics, Feedback etc.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: But as no opt-in is needed, so how the identifier can be carry by usual push notification? if they are using background process then what if the app is being killed?

Comment: A Push Notification can carry 256 bytes payload and in addition to usual alert,sound and badge you can add custom values. In this case the unique event identifier. I didn't say they are using background process. On every login, the device token is passed to server, along with that they can also check for any new events for that user. So for rich push to work, user should run their app.